# TeamCity symbol server not serving symbols

Tags: teamcity, debug-symbols

I'm trying to implement the TeamCity [Symbol Server](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Symbol+Server) for my internal NuGet packages, however the symbols are not loading.
I'm following the instructions as per [this blog](http://www.stefanprodan.eu/2013/09/teamcity-symbol-server/) which is standard advice for symbol server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TeamCity Symbol Server plugin page showed the url to use was

```
http://ourserver/app/symbols/
```

The fix was to drop the trailing slash

```
http://ourserver/app/symbols
```

Hitting that URL gives a 404 but that is the format that works for Visual Studio 2012 and when trying to verify the symbols via symchk.exe

eg:

```
symchk /r mylibrary.dll /s SRV*http://outserver.acp.net/app/symbols
```

Using that URL then renders for a basic auth logon prompt and symbols load correctly

Comment: Where can i find the symchk command? i installed windows sdk but i still cant find it

Comment: Did you actually get this working with _Nuget packages_? I can't seem to get TeamCity to recognize that the Nuget Pack build step actually created any symbols (even though the .symbols.nupkg file is right there as an artifact).

Comment: Briefly yes but then disabled it due to some build issues. Now using https://github.com/GitTools/GitLink instead