# Teamcity as Symbol Server no pdbs found

Tags: teamcity, debug-symbols, symbol-server

I am trying to use Teamcity as Symbol Server. I set Up TC like I should and TC is indexing my files.

I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471597/teamcity-symbol-server-not-serving-symbols/21471598#21471598) question so I tried it to find the symbols on the server. I get some .dll listed with the command `symchk /r * /s SRV*http://outserver.acp.net/app/symbols`. I Only see other dlls but not my libraries or pdbs.

What did i miss?

A short Log:

```
[14:45:48]Indexing sources appeared in file C:\BuildAgent\work\8652c4bdd8dd2154\***\File.pdb
[14:45:48]Information about 7 source files was updated
[14:45:53]Collecting symbol files signatures.
[14:45:53]Running command C:\BuildAgent\plugins\symbol-server\bin\JetBrains.CommandLine.Symbols.exe dumpSymbolSign /o="C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\symbol-signatures-8701232224987713334.xml" /i="C:\BuildAgent\temp\globalTmp\dumpSymbolSign5535309674029756055.input"
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?